# Transform the differential equation using new coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, transformation

Transform the following differential equation using new coordinates $y = x$ and $s = \log(t)$
$$2t^2\ddot x + 3t\dot x + xe^{-t} = 2/t $$

Now I understand $\tau(s) = t$ and $s = \sigma(t)$ as well as $\eta(t,x) = y$

but I have only performed a coordinate transformation for first order equations. How is this extended to 2nd order?

I am looking simply for the transformed function, not the solution

I assume you start with taking the second partial derivatives of the coordinates transformations, but any clarity would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Putting $y(s)=x(e^s)$ you have $ x(t)=y (\log t)$, so

$$\dot x(t)=\frac{ \dot y (\log t)}{t}$$

$$\ddot x(t) = \frac{ \ddot y (\log t) - \dot y (\log t)}{t^2}$$

Plug those expressions in your ODE and see what you come up with.

Comment: how did you know to those specific equations for $y(s)$ and $x(t)$ ? I understand $t = e^s$ so are you simply substituting for $t$ in $x(t)$?

Comment: @Clark I don't understand your question. Are you asking how did I derive the expressions for $\dot {x}(t)$ and $\ddot{x}(t)$ that I wrote?

Comment: My question gets back to: given $y = x$ and $s = log(t)$ how did you know to say $y(s) = x(e^s)$ and $x(t) = y(log t)$

Comment: Well that is given to you. You have been given the change of variable $s=\log t$ or equivalently $e^s=e^{\log t} = t$ and then you use it to define a reparametrization  $y(t) = x(e^s) $ or equivalently $y(s) = x(\log t) $. Then you get an easier equation in terms of $y(s) $.

Comment: Perfect! I was misunderstanding the underlying independent variable in $y = x$ as it could be $y(t) = x(t)$ or $y(s) = x(s)$